# Order multidimensional array according to a second array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to order `$ArrayToOrder` according to column `SecondArrayField2` in `$SecondArray`, where the link between the two arrays are `Field_3` (in $ArrayToOrder) and `SecondArrayField1` in $SecondArray.

```
$ArrayToOrder=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 13
            [Field_2] => 15
            [Field_3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 25
            [Field_2] => 17
            [Field_3] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 121
            [Field_2] => 20
            [Field_3] => 11
        )
)

$SecondArray=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SecondArrayField1] => 11
            [SecondArrayField2] => Bruce                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SecondArrayField1] => 3
            [SecondArrayField2] => Arthur
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SecondArrayField1] => 2
            [SecondArrayField2] => Mary
        )
)
```

Desired result as follows:

```
$ArrayToOrder=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 13
            [Field_2] => 15
            [Field_3] => 3 //(Arthur)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 121
            [Field_2] => 20
            [Field_3] => 11 //(Bruce)                  
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 25
            [Field_2] => 17
            [Field_3] => 2 //(Mary)
        )
)
```

Comment: customary : tried and error?

Comment: Assuming that the values of SecondArrayField1 are unique, I would first transform this into a flat array, that uses SecondArrayField1 as key and SecondArrayField2 as the value - then you can simply look up the name corresponding to the Field_3 value in there. Wrapped in a custom little compare function to feed to `usort`, and … done.

Comment: This is a specification and not a request for help with a coding issue. **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort on your behalf to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being asked. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've been in this site for a while, although coding is not my business. I agree with you that showing coding effort is rather mandatoy, but in this case I would not know how to start with the _logic_ of the solution. Anyway, there is no need for a full solution. A comment like the one from 04FS is just enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is snippet you can use,

```
// first fetching key as SecondArrayField2 and SecondArrayField1 as value
$Field_3 = array_column($SecondArray, "SecondArrayField1","SecondArrayField2");
// sort by key alphabetically
ksort($Field_3);
//
$sorted = array_values(array_map(function($v) use ($ArrayToOrder) {
    // first fetched Field_3 matching with current value of $Field_3 in the order
    // get the index of matching Field_3
    // save it to sorted array its sub array
    return $ArrayToOrder[array_search($v, array_column($ArrayToOrder,'Field_3'))];
}, $Field_3));
print_r($sorted);die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/peG1q).

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 13
            [Field_2] => 15
            [Field_3] => 3 //(Arthur)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 121
            [Field_2] => 20
            [Field_3] => 11 // (Bruce)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Field_1] => 25
            [Field_2] => 17
            [Field_3] => 2 // (Mary)
        )

)
```